# r shiny selectInput - selectable classes in only one column

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to R and shiny. I have a problem that I could not solve.

I have a histogram where I want to make the classes separately selectable. 
The classes are all in one column. To make them separately selectable, I did not succeed.

How do I get it to work?

Thanks a lot

```
## app.R ##

set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(Class = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 30, replace = TRUE),
                 Amount = sample(5:20, 30, replace = TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors= FALSE, check.names = FALSE)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

  output$sum = renderPrint({

    summary(df)
  })

  output$str = renderPrint({

    str(df)
  })

  output$data = renderTable({

    colm = as.numeric(input$var)
    df[colm]
    head(df)
  })

  output$myhist <- renderPlot({

    colm = as.numeric(input$var)
    hist(df$Amount, col =input$colour, xlim = c(0, max(df$Amount)), main = "Histogram", breaks = seq(0, max(df$Amount),l=input$bin+1), 
         xlab = names(df$Amount)
    )}
  )  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var", label = "1. Select Class", 
                  choices = c("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3, "D"= 4, "E" = 5),
                  selected = 2), 

      sliderInput("bin", "2. Select the number of histogram BINs by using the slider below", min=5, max=25, value=15),

      radioButtons("colour", label = "3. Select the color of histogram",
                   choices = c("Green", "Red",
                               "Blue"), selected = "Green")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("myhist")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("sum")),
                  tabPanel("Structure", verbatimTextOutput("str")),
                  tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("data"))
                  ) 
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

Allow the selectInput to have multiple selections, by adding `multiple = TRUE`:

`selectInput("var", label = "1. Select Class", choices = c("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3, "D"= 4, "E" = 5), multiple = TRUE)`

Use a checkbox group:

`checkboxGroupInput('var', label = "1. Select Class", choices = c("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3, "D"= 4, "E" = 5))`

I recommend the 2nd option, using a checkbox group, as I believe they are easy for users to understand.

**EDIT**
As requested here is the full code, with the checkbox group linked to the chart:

```
## app.R ##

library(shiny)

set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(Class = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 30, replace = TRUE),
                 Amount = sample(5:20, 30, replace = TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors= FALSE, check.names = FALSE)


server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })

    output$sum = renderPrint({

        summary(df)
    })

    output$str = renderPrint({

        str(df)
    })

    output$data = renderTable({

        colm = as.numeric(input$var)
        df[colm]
        head(df)
    })

    output$myhist <- renderPlot({

        df_plot <- df[df$Class %in% input$var, ]

        hist(df_plot$Amount, col = input$colour, xlim = c(0, max(df_plot$Amount)), main = "Histogram", breaks = seq(0, max(df_plot$Amount),l=input$bin+1), 
             xlab = names(df_plot$Amount)
        )}
    )  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput('var', label = "1. Select Class", choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), selected = "B"),

            sliderInput("bin", "2. Select the number of histogram BINs by using the slider below", min=5, max=25, value=15),

            radioButtons("colour", label = "3. Select the color of histogram",
                         choices = c("Green", "Red",
                                     "Blue"), selected = "Green")

        ),

        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("myhist")),
                        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("sum")),
                        tabPanel("Structure", verbatimTextOutput("str")),
                        tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("data"))
            ) 
        )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer #Ash, I will use the 2nd option. Unfortunately there is still the problem that all values of the classes are displayed on the diagram at the same time.  Turning the checkboxes on or off has no effect. Not only the class "A" or "B" can be displayed on the histogram, all of them are shown.
I guess that the `choices = c("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3, "D"= 4, "E" = 5)` only refer to collons but not rows.

Comment: @Skruff I've edited the answer to show how to link the checkbox group to the chart.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Many, many thanks @Ash. Great community!